# how to find greatest common divisor inside smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, c++, compilation, error

I need the **greatest common divisor** between two numbers in the smart contract. I tried:

```
int gcd = __gcd(num1, num2);
```

`num1` and `num2` are two numbers. When the smart contract is compiled, its generating error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier '__gcd'

I also tried `std::__gcd` but no use. It seems EOS doesn't support `__gcd`. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `#include <numeric>` to use `std::gcd` in your code.